# Recommendation to overcome Lambda function timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services

My lambda function needs to process the records in excel file around 2000 records but in the 15 min am able to process only 500 records how can I proceed with this scenario, I have given full memory

Comment: Well wait one hour then, jk. Please provide the code you are using and some sample data, only then someone can help you

Comment: What you want is called a "profiler".

Comment: Why do you wish to use Lambda? What is your actual end-goal? That is, what does the Excel file contain, what are you "processing" and what are you doing with the results of the process? There might be a different approach you could take but without more information, we cannot assist.

Answer (score 1):

You really only have two options if you want to use lambda - either make your code run faster so that it will finish in time, or split up the task so that it can be done by multiple lambdas concurrently.

To split it up, one way would be to have one lambda function that all it does it take your 2000 rows from the excel data and puts out 2000 messages to an SQS queue, and then let multiple lambda process the messages out of the queue.

Sounds to me like you are tying to do too much within a single lambda invocation, not really what it was designed for.

If you really can't split up the work into discrete parts, and can't figure out how to make the lambda run faster, then I would use an EC2 instance to process the file instead.